# Approach to encrypt/ password protect some documents

Tags: windows, encryption, file-transfer, password-encryption

I got a requirement from my client that he wishes to encrypt/ password protect some of the documents, before sending over to another user in another regional office.

By not writing the password into the email body.

How can the user in another regional office knows the password to decrypt/ open the protected documents?

What approach should be adopted? Is there any standard/ algorithm I can refer to? But we prefer not to use any 3rd party software/ utility.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, key management and distribution is a very hard problem. Options include telephone, SMS, postal mail, courier, a second email depending on the required security level.

Comment: tks for the comment.

yes, would like to know further about the key management and distribution. can you elaborate further?

a second email is not the option as the email account could be compromised.

Comment: Consider how debit crd PINs are distributed: generally postal mail. Secure hardware such as HSMs are distributed by a carrier who has possession 100% of the time. An HTTPS connection with TLS 1.2, perfect forward secrecy, a well trusted CA and certificate pinning seems to be a reasonable solution. But it all depends on how paranoid you are.